# Adding a link to an email address within SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, email

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to SharePoint. My company has recently updated from 2003 to 2010 and i'm trying to re-build my SharePoint site within 2010.

In the existing site, I've been able to create a number of links which when clicked launch an email to an set address. Is this possible in 2010?

N.B - i'm editing 2010 using Rich Text as opposed to HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you typing the link content? on a field/column of a list item? Directly on a wiki page? Is it in a Content Editor Web Part?

Answer (score 2):

Where are you entering the email addresses?

- Is it a column in a list?

  The best column type to use is Hyperlink, prefixing your email
  address with `mailto:` instead of `http://` for websites
- Is it in a Content Editor Web Part?

  If so, there should be a link button in the toolbar for the text area
  you are typing in. Highlight the text to be clicked and click the
  toolbar button, which should look like a world and/or chain. Again,
  add your email address with the prefix `mailto:`

Answer (score 0):

If you have some difficulties in editing html in Content Editor Web Part you can
just use "Edit html source" option.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4988.sharepoint-2010-how-to-add-html-content-into-the-content-editor-webpart.aspx

There you can create/copy html as in regular web site.
Only one problem: if you add your custom JavaScript using this option it will be
removed by SharePoint.